# Windows Phone 8.1 app crashes during resume (possibly because it hangs during suspend)

Tags: c#, crash, windows-phone-8.1, crash-dumps, suspend

I have a situation where my application crashes sometimes during the suspend/resume process. The scenario looks like this:

1. The application runs normally.
2. The user exits the application by an action like tapping the start button, using a file picker or launching another application. 
   At this point the application suspend event handler is executed. According to all the investigation and logs I produce I know that the suspend event handler is executed without error. The deferral object (part of the suspension process) is marked as complete. 
   Typically the suspend process takes 200-500 milliseconds.
3. After a short interval the user returns to the application.
4. The OS shows the “Resuming…” message for a few seconds.
5. Once in a while (it is rather hard to repro) the “Resuming…” message disappears and the OS start screen is shown – indicative of the fact that the app crashed. 
   According to all the investigation and logs I produce I know that the resuming event handler is not called.
6. When the app crashes the OS creates an application dump file.

Taking the app dump file and examining it using WinDBG shows a call stack like the ones I have at the end of the post. I have captured 5 such dump files and all show a call stack that has `Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::OnAfterAppSuspend`. Following that method I have either something that shows `CoreClr!CLRServicesImpl::FinalizerThreadWait` or something that shows `CoreClr!CLRServicesImpl::GarbageCollect`.

**Questions**

- Based on these callstacks, can I assume that after my suspend event handler executes successfully the application hangs in some core portion of the framework?
- Is this indicative of a bug in the framework that manifests in some rare cases involving the suspend process? Or could this be still caused by a bug in my code?
- Does anyone have any insight to share based on the callstacks shown here?

Here are two examples of a WinDBG analysis of two of these dump files:

```
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000 ??       ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: c0000194
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

BUGCHECK_STR:  c0000194

PROCESS_NAME:  MyApplication.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000194 - {EXCEPTION}  Possible deadlock condition.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000194 - {EXCEPTION}  Possible deadlock condition.

CRITICAL_SECTION:  00000000 -- (!cs -s 00000000)

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  MyApplication.exe

MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 x86fre

MANAGED_CODE: 1

MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE:  CoreClr

MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER:  SOS

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:  

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType
-- --- ------- --------------------------
   6   a84.d98 Unknown                

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~6s;k;;

BLOCKING_THREAD:  00000d98

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang_Memory

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 76f8712c to 76f872e6

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000d98

STACK_TEXT:  
038de580 76f8712c : 05744d90 036ebad0 036d09e8 05744d1c : ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext+0xf2
038de5f0 75c79a8c : 05744d90 48d2d5b6 ffffffff 00000002 : ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x9c
038de680 75c794a4 : 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 : CoreMessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+0x14870
038de6d8 75d04b84 : ffffffff 00000001 8000ffff 00c1eef8 : CoreMessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+0x14288
038de758 75d04994 : 00000001 038de764 0a613db8 ffffffff : minuser!Core::Yield::gggIMessageLoopExtensions_Wait+0x148
038de7b8 75d044fe : 038de8e8 ffffffff 00000001 00000000 : minuser!Core::CoreUIAdapter::gggWait+0x3c
038de808 75d04158 : ffffffff 00000001 00000340 00000000 : minuser!Core::ThreadInfo::gggWaitForObjectsImpl+0x35a
038de8c8 75d0402c : ffffffff 00000040 00000016 00000010 : minuser!Core::ThreadInfo::gggWaitForObjects+0x68
038dea18 75d03cb0 : ffffffff 00000040 00000016 00c7fb70 : minuser!Core::Api::gggMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x144
038dea70 76cb3590 : 00000040 00000016 8000ffff 00c7fb70 : minuser!minMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x50
038deae8 76cb30f0 : 00000016 038decd0 038decd0 76cc5eeb : combase!ASTAWaitContext::KernelWait+0x40
038deb28 76ce7a2a : 00000001 00000000 00000000 038ded4c : combase!ASTAWaitContext::Wait+0x288
038decb8 76ce798e : 00000000 038ded4c 00000002 08963dfc : combase!ASTAWaitInNewContext+0x6a
038ded30 76cc5606 : 00000001 00000000 00000002 ffffffff : combase!ASTAThreadWaitForHandles+0x4e
038ded68 6e2a88c2 : 038ded98 00bef138 76cc55c9 00000000 : combase!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0x3e
038ded90 6e2a856c : 038ded98 00000000 00000080 00000000 : CoreClr!MsgWaitHelper+0x3a
038dedb8 6e2a8378 : 00000001 00bef138 00000000 00000001 : CoreClr!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x38
038dede0 6e2a824e : ffffffff 00000001 00000000 00000000 : CoreClr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0xa8
038dee40 6e2b82f6 : ffffffff 00000001 76d69fb0 76d6a034 : CoreClr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x4e
038deea0 6e30fd58 : ffffffff 00000001 00000000 00000000 : CoreClr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x4a
038deed0 6e30fbe4 : 00bef198 6e30c195 00c99ffc 00000000 : CoreClr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWait+0xa0
038def18 68db2f04 : 00000000 038def48 00000001 038defa0 : CoreClr!CLRServicesImpl::FinalizerThreadWait+0x54
038def68 68d0a5fe : 00000000 00000000 038def80 68d0a5ff : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ReferenceTrackerManager::TriggerFinalization+0x1c
038def78 68d065ac : 00000000 00c85f58 038def98 68d065ad : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::OnAfterAppSuspend+0x22
038def88 68d06c84 : 00000000 68d0556d 00000000 00c85f58 : Windows_UI_Xaml!XAML::PLM::PLMHandler::InvokeAfterAppSuspendCallback+0x18
038defa0 68d0592c : 04401e24 038defa0 fffffffe fffffffe : Windows_UI_Xaml!XAML::PLM::PLMHandler::DecrementAppSuspendActivityCount+0x74
038defc8 6bb904d2 : 038defdc 04461088 038df020 6bb904d3 : Windows_UI_Xaml!XAML::PLM::SuspendingDeferralWrapper::Complete+0x20
038defd8 0bff3bda : af01fbe9 6e512454 038df858 00000000 : WINDOWS_NI+0x4004d2
038df028 6d9a1594 : 038df148 00000000 00000000 00000000 : 0xbff3bda
038df0f8 6d991992 : 6da288ad 00e765d0 038df140 6d991993 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f1594
038df108 6d9918fa : 038df130 00e74044 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e1992
038df148 6d9a14f0 : 6d9a14a1 00000000 00e9b1f0 6d9a14f1 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e18fa
038df158 6d9a34da : 038df180 6a550247 010bc7dc 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f14f0
038df178 6d9a3328 : 6da288ad 6d9a3329 00000000 00e7408c : mscorlib_ni+0x1f34da
038df180 6d9a322a : 00000000 00e7408c 010d16ac 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f3328
038df1a8 6d9bd0e2 : 00cd3010 00e79370 010d1668 010d16ac : mscorlib_ni+0x1f322a
038df1c8 6d9bcea6 : 038df2e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x20d0e2
038df200 6dae0210 : 00000000 010d163c 038df214 6dae0211 : mscorlib_ni+0x20cea6
038df210 6d9a15ea : 00cd3010 038df22c 6d9a15eb 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x330210
038df220 6d9c06d2 : 038df23c 010d1680 00000001 038df248 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f15ea
038df238 069444d2 : 038df1e0 038df200 04461088 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x2106d2
038df250 6d9a1594 : 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 : 0x69444d2
038df298 6d991992 : 6da288ad 00e765d0 038df2e0 6d991993 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f1594
038df2a8 6d9918fa : 038df2d0 00e74044 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e1992
038df2e8 6d9a14f0 : 6d9a14a1 00000000 00e9b1f0 6d9a14f1 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e18fa
038df2f8 6d9a34da : 038df320 6a550247 010d160c 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f14f0
038df318 6d9a3328 : 6da288ad 6d9a3329 00000000 00e7408c : mscorlib_ni+0x1f34da
038df320 6d9a322a : 00000000 00e7408c 010d1694 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f3328
038df348 6d9bd0e2 : 00cd3010 00e79370 010d15c0 010d1694 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f322a
038df368 6d9bcea6 : 5da24741 00000000 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x20d0e2
038df3a0 6dae0210 : 00000000 010d1594 038df3b4 6dae0211 : mscorlib_ni+0x20cea6
038df3b0 6d9a15ea : 00cd3010 038df3cc 6d9a15eb 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x330210
038df3c0 6d9c06d2 : 038df3dc 010d15dc 00000001 038df3e8 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f15ea
038df3d8 06944c58 : 00000000 6e266900 00000010 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x2106d2
038df3f0 6d9a1594 : 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 : 0x6944c58
038df4a0 6d991992 : 6da288ad 00e765d0 038df4e8 6d991993 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f1594
038df4b0 6d9918fa : 038df4d8 00e74044 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e1992
038df4f0 6d9a14f0 : 6d9a14a1 00000000 00e9b1f0 6d9a14f1 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e18fa
038df500 6d9a34da : 038df528 6a550247 010d1564 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f14f0
038df520 6d9a3328 : 6da288ad 6d9a3329 00000000 00e7408c : mscorlib_ni+0x1f34da
038df528 6d9a322a : 00000000 00e7408c 010d15f4 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f3328
038df550 6d9bd0e2 : 00cd3010 00e79370 010d1510 010d15f4 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f322a
038df570 6d9bcea6 : 038df584 00000000 038df5c8 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x20d0e2
038df5a8 6dae0210 : 00000000 010d14e4 038df5bc 6dae0211 : mscorlib_ni+0x20cea6
038df5b8 6d9a15ea : 00cd3010 038df5d4 6d9a15eb 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x330210
038df5c8 6d9c06d2 : 038df5e4 010d1530 00000001 038df5f0 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f15ea
038df5e0 06946192 : 00000000 038df600 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x2106d2
038df5f8 6d9a1594 : 00000002 00000000 00000000 00000000 : 0x6946192
038df6b0 6d991992 : 6da288ad 00e765d0 038df6f8 6d991993 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f1594
038df6c0 6d9918fa : 00000006 00e74044 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e1992
038df700 6d9a14f0 : 6d9a14a1 00000000 00000001 6d9a14f1 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e18fa
038df710 6d9a344e : 00000000 00000000 010d14b4 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f14f0
038df730 6a55042a : 6da288ad 6a55042b fffffffe fffffffe : mscorlib_ni+0x1f344e
038df738 6a55040e : fffffffe fffffffe 43f93602 75d03c61 : System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_NI+0x3042a
038df758 6d991992 : 6a53b54d 6d991993 038df7a0 00e74044 : System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_NI+0x3040e
038df760 6d9918fa : 038df7a0 00e74044 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e1992
038df7a0 6a5503da : 6a550391 00000000 04461088 6a5503db : mscorlib_ni+0x1e18fa
038df7b0 6bbbbf8a : 00000002 00000000 038df86c 04461088 : System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_NI+0x303da
038df7c8 6e1917a4 : 6a550391 00000002 00bdf158 038df7e0 : WINDOWS_NI+0x42bf8a
038df7e0 6e1ef0f2 : 6a550391 04461088 6e5537c4 6e1ef0f3 : CoreClr!COMToCLRDispatchHelper+0x3c
038df7f0 6e19175c : 010c5e74 41e95b6e d62d8da2 00b5948f : CoreClr!COMToCLRWorker+0x142
038df850 6a5c76ee : 00000000 af01fbe9 6e5126e8 ffffffff : CoreClr!GenericComCallStub+0x18
038df8b8 6a5c7320 : 41e95b6e d62d8da2 00b5948f 038df920 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x349e
038df978 74e71616 : 00001cff 00000006 00000000 00000002 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x30d0
038dfa20 74e71350 : 065278b0 06527898 0a6cbb40 06527898 : twinapi_appcore!Event::WaitAndProcessEvents+0x42
038dfa38 74e7117e : 74ea7128 74ea600c 038dfa80 74e7117f : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::SuspendingDeferral::WaitForOutstandingDeferrals+0x30
038dfa48 74e71098 : 00000000 00c7fb70 065194e8 00000000 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::SuspendResume+0xd6
038dfa98 74e7163e : 76ccfea1 08aeee88 038dfab0 74e7163f : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::Details::CreateClassFactory<Microsoft::WRL::SimpleClassFactory<CPackageDebugSettings,0> >+0xb8
038dfaa8 6a5c76ee : 74e71631 76ccfea1 038dfb70 6a5c76ef : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::Details::InvokeHelper<Microsoft::WRL::Implements<Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,Windows::UI::Core::IDispatchedHandler,Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil>,<lambda_806d9f75e467416c61267ff2e6219463>,0>::Invoke+0xe
038dfab8 6a5c7320 : 41e95b6e d62d8da2 00b5948f 038dfb20 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x349e
038dfb78 6a5c7136 : 00000000 00000006 001f0000 00000001 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x30d0
038dfc20 68d96112 : 00000000 00c9b210 038dfca0 76ce7a49 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x2ee6
038dfc88 68d96082 : 06527898 00c940b0 038dfcc0 68d96083 : Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop+0x3a
038dfc98 68d95f3e : ffffffff 80004005 038dfcd8 76ce798f : Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterControl::RunMessageLoop+0x1a
038dfcc8 68d95f12 : 00c99ff8 00000000 fffffffe fffffffe : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop+0x26
038dfcf0 74e7257a : 038dfd00 74e7257b 74e72555 74ea600c : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkView::Run+0xe
038dfcf8 74e7244a : 74e72555 74ea600c 038dfd30 74e7244b : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run+0x26
038dfd08 756eff28 : 038dfd18 00c82de8 00c7fa78 00c82de8 : twinapi_appcore!CWrlLightweightHandlerBase::ReleaseMarshalData+0x11a
038dfd38 76fb7cf6 : 00000000 00b1f0a8 00000000 00000000 : shcore!SHCreateThreadRef+0x200
038dfdc8 00000000 : 00000000 76fb7ce1 00000000 00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x16


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
CoreMessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+14870
75c79a8c 4604     mov         r4,r0

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  coremessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+14870

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: CoreMessaging

IMAGE_NAME:  CoreMessaging.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  537ed848

STACK_COMMAND:  ~6s ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  c0000194_coremessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+14870

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  c0000194_coremessaging!CoreUIConfigureTestHost+14870

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang_Memory

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  c0000194

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  CoreMessaging.dll

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  CoreUIConfigureTestHost

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  CoreMessaging.dll!CoreUIConfigureTestHost

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang_Memory_c0000194_CoreMessaging.dll!CoreUIConfigureTestHost

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:application_hang_busyhang_memory_c0000194_coremessaging.dll!coreuiconfiguretesthost

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {dc0dae9e-51e6-dcc9-477c-d9461a807d07}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Another example:

```
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for WINDOWS.NI.WINMD
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for WINDOWS.NI.WINMD
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MyApplication.exe
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for user32.dll - 

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
user32                 PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

You can troubleshoot most symbol related issues by turning on symbol loading diagnostics (!sym noisy) and repeating the command that caused symbols to be loaded.
You should also verify that your symbol search path (.sympath) is correct.
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for CoreMessaging.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for windows.ui.xaml.phone.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for Windows.UI.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ShellRuntime.dll - 
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Net.Http.Phone.ni.DLL
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for System.Net.Http.Phone.ni.DLL
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for xamlpalwp.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ie_shims.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for jwrcore.DLL - 

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000 ??       ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: c0000194
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

BUGCHECK_STR:  c0000194

PROCESS_NAME:  MyApplication.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000194 - {EXCEPTION}  Possible deadlock condition.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000194 - {EXCEPTION}  Possible deadlock condition.

CRITICAL_SECTION:  00000000 -- (!cs -s 00000000)

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  MyApplication.exe

MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 x86fre

MANAGED_CODE: 1

MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE:  CoreClr

MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER:  SOS

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:  

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType
-- --- ------- --------------------------
   6   aec.fc8 Unknown                

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~6s;k;;

BLOCKING_THREAD:  00000fc8

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 6e565342 to 6e506aac

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000fc8

STACK_TEXT:  
0313efd8 6e565342 : 0313f050 6e565343 00000001 00000000 : CoreClr!ComCallWrapper::GetObjectRef+0x8
0313efe0 6e56525e : 00000001 00000000 0313eff8 68baa0e5 : CoreClr!RCWRefCache::AddReferenceUsingDependentHandle+0xbe
0313f058 68a8a750 : 0313f078 689a3e45 689a3e11 098419c8 : CoreClr!CFindDependentWrappersCallback::OnFoundDependentWrapper+0x76
0313f080 68a8a6f2 : 098419c0 00000001 0313f098 68a8a6f3 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::TrackerTargetReferenceBase::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x2c
0313f090 689a4194 : 0827289c 00000000 0313f0c0 689a4195 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ModifiedEffectiveValue::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x26
0313f0a0 689a4166 : 08240970 08240808 08155dcc 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x15c
0313f0c8 689a4166 : 08240b98 08240790 08155514 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f0f0 689a4166 : 08240ad8 08240aa8 099df628 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f118 689a4166 : 08239338 0823d8c8 099de648 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f140 689a4166 : 08239368 0823d670 0815fdb8 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f168 689a4166 : 082396c8 08239728 099def98 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f190 689a4166 : 07f3fd50 07f3fc30 08270e74 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f1b8 689a4166 : 07f3fcc0 07f3fe28 08271b1c 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f1e0 689a4166 : 07f3fd38 07f3fea0 08270b14 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f208 68baa0e4 : 07f3f9f0 07f3f9d8 09a76780 00000001 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f230 68a8a692 : 09a7925c 09a79260 0313f250 68a8a693 : Windows_UI_Xaml!CWindowRenderTarget::Draw+0x495b8
0313f240 689a44e4 : 68a8a665 09a766b8 00000001 68f43004 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkElement::OnReferenceTrackerWalk+0x2e
0313f258 689a4086 : 09a76680 00000000 0313f288 689a4087 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ComposingTrackerExtensionWrapper::OnReferenceTrackerWalk+0x28
0313f268 689a4166 : 00000000 689a4039 07f06304 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x4e
0313f290 68baa0e4 : 07f44a30 07fab7c8 060ba9a0 00000001 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f2b8 68a8a692 : 07eb2c6c 07eb2c7c 0313f2d8 68a8a693 : Windows_UI_Xaml!CWindowRenderTarget::Draw+0x495b8
0313f2c8 689a44e4 : 68a8a665 060ba8bc 00000001 68f43004 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkElement::OnReferenceTrackerWalk+0x2e
0313f2e0 689a4086 : 060ba884 00000000 0313f310 689a4087 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ComposingTrackerExtensionWrapper::OnReferenceTrackerWalk+0x28
0313f2f0 689a4166 : 00000000 689a4039 05ff38c0 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x4e
0313f318 689a4166 : 07cb9990 07cb98a0 05ff37e0 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f340 689a4112 : 07b4dfd0 07cbab18 060c0e88 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f368 689a4166 : 00693ca8 00693d28 046d91b4 00000000 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0xda
0313f390 68a8a312 : 07d11e50 07d11cd0 07d16d30 00000001 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x12e
0313f3b8 6a38038e : 07f51fcc 00000001 0313f3d8 6a38038f : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::TrackerPtrWrapper::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x22
0313f3c8 689a44e4 : 060ddfcc 00000001 68f43004 00000001 : windows_ui_xaml_phone!XamlControlsGetPlatformMetadataProvider+0x96d2
0313f3e0 689a4086 : 060ddf94 00000000 0313f410 689a4087 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ComposingTrackerExtensionWrapper::OnReferenceTrackerWalk+0x28
0313f3f0 68a9f570 : 00000000 689a4039 68f43004 060ddf90 : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::ReferenceTrackerWalk+0x4e
0313f418 6e47486a : 060b0980 060ddf90 0313f448 6e47486b : Windows_UI_Xaml!ctl::WeakReferenceSourceNoThreadId::FindTrackerTargets+0x30
0313f428 6e47475e : 0313f438 6e58dadb 6e796364 07bc5020 : CoreClr!RCWWalker::WalkOneRCW+0x36
0313f450 6e5386cc : 0a069008 00000d2b 00000915 0a35f738 : CoreClr!RCWRefCache::EnumerateAllJupiterRCWs<long (__cdecl*)(RCW *,RCWRefCache *),RCWRefCache *>+0x56
0313f490 6e5874ea : 689a3e11 0069f6d0 00000000 0069f6d0 : CoreClr!RCWWalker::WalkRCWs+0x88
0313f528 6e587488 : 0313f540 6e587489 00000000 6e7d8d0c : CoreClr!RCWWalker::OnGCStartedWorker+0x36
0313f530 6e587376 : 00000000 6e7d8d0c 00684278 6e7d3964 : CoreClr!SetupFailFastFilterAndCall+0x10
0313f548 6e53aeca : 00000001 6e7d9a40 0313f588 6e53aecb : CoreClr!CNameSpace::GcStartWork+0x1e
0313f558 6e52eb24 : 0313f588 6e477ba3 00000000 6e7d37c4 : CoreClr!WKS::gc_heap::garbage_collect+0x122
0313f590 6e58c1e0 : 8000000d ffffff82 6e7d9b08 00000009 : CoreClr!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration+0xbc
0313f5d8 6e58c02a : 005ef138 6e58c195 0069f6d4 00000000 : CoreClr!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollect+0x4c
0313f600 68b136b8 : 00000000 6b5919d4 00a98cb8 0313f648 : CoreClr!CLRServicesImpl::GarbageCollect+0x7a
0313f670 68a6a5fa : 00000000 00000000 0313f688 68a6a5fb : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ReferenceTrackerManager::TriggerCollectionForSuspend+0x1c
0313f680 68a665ac : 00000000 00683f78 0313f6a0 68a665ad : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::OnAfterAppSuspend+0x1e
0313f690 68a66c84 : 00000000 68a6556d 00000000 00683f78 : Windows_UI_Xaml!XAML::PLM::PLMHandler::InvokeAfterAppSuspendCallback+0x18
0313f6a8 68a6592c : 006ce614 0313f6a8 fffffffe fffffffe : Windows_UI_Xaml!XAML::PLM::PLMHandler::DecrementAppSuspendActivityCount+0x74
0313f6d0 6b9004d2 : 0313f6e4 03d5a838 0313f728 6b9004d3 : Windows_UI_Xaml!XAML::PLM::SuspendingDeferralWrapper::Complete+0x20
0313f6e0 0b2a7f36 : 6b592b21 6e792454 0313f9a0 00000000 : WINDOWS_NI+0x4004d2
0313f730 6dc21594 : 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 : 0xb2a7f36
0313f7f8 6dc11992 : 6dca88ad 008365d0 0313f840 6dc11993 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f1594
0313f808 6dc118fa : 00000006 00834044 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e1992
0313f848 6dc214f0 : 6dc214a1 00000000 00000001 6dc214f1 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e18fa
0313f858 6dc2344e : 0313f910 00000000 00a9046c 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f14f0
0313f878 6a79042a : 6dca88ad 6a79042b fffffffe b74c0365 : mscorlib_ni+0x1f344e
0313f880 6a79040e : fffffffe b74c0365 0313f8e0 0313f8e4 : System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_NI+0x3042a
0313f8a0 6dc11992 : 6a77b54d 6dc11993 fa67b90e 00834044 : System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_NI+0x3040e
0313f8a8 6dc118fa : fa67b90e 00834044 00000000 00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x1e1992
0313f8e8 6a7903da : 6a790391 00000000 03d5a838 6a7903db : mscorlib_ni+0x1e18fa
0313f8f8 6b92bf8a : 00000002 00000000 0313f9b4 03d5a838 : System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_NI+0x303da
0313f910 6e4117a4 : 6a790391 01d10b68 000a07df 0313f928 : WINDOWS_NI+0x42bf8a
0313f928 6e46f0f2 : 6a790391 03d5a838 6e7d37c4 6e46f0f3 : CoreClr!COMToCLRDispatchHelper+0x3c
0313f938 6e41175c : 00a98cb8 41e95b6e d62d8da2 00b5948f : CoreClr!COMToCLRWorker+0x142
0313f998 6b0376ee : 00000000 6b592b21 6e7926e8 ffffffff : CoreClr!GenericComCallStub+0x18
0313fa00 6b037320 : 41e95b6e d62d8da2 00b5948f 0313fa68 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x349e
0313fac0 75181616 : 00001cff 00000006 00000000 00000002 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x30d0
0313fb68 75181350 : 05e14a00 05e149e8 09bdec10 05e149e8 : twinapi_appcore!Event::WaitAndProcessEvents+0x42
0313fb80 7518117e : 751b7128 751b600c 0313fbc8 7518117f : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::SuspendingDeferral::WaitForOutstandingDeferrals+0x30
0313fb90 75181098 : 00000000 0067fa18 04718700 00000000 : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::SuspendResume+0xd6
0313fbe0 7518163e : 76f8fea1 0a104e80 0313fbf8 7518163f : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::Details::CreateClassFactory<Microsoft::WRL::SimpleClassFactory<CPackageDebugSettings,0> >+0xb8
0313fbf0 6b0376ee : 75181631 76f8fea1 0313fcb8 6b0376ef : twinapi_appcore!Microsoft::WRL::Details::InvokeHelper<Microsoft::WRL::Implements<Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,Windows::UI::Core::IDispatchedHandler,Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil>,<lambda_806d9f75e467416c61267ff2e6219463>,0>::Invoke+0xe
0313fc00 6b037454 : 41e95b6e d62d8da2 00b5948f 03292730 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x349e
0313fcc0 6b037136 : 00000001 00000006 001f0000 00000001 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x3204
0313fd68 68af6112 : 00000000 00696710 0313fde8 76fa7a49 : Windows_UI!Ordinal1500+0x2ee6
0313fdd0 68af6082 : 05e149e8 0062e180 0313fe08 68af6083 : Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop+0x3a
0313fde0 68af5f3e : ffffffff 80004005 0313fe20 76fa798f : Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterControl::RunMessageLoop+0x1a
0313fe10 68af5f12 : 0069f6d0 00000000 fffffffe fffffffe : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop+0x26
0313fe38 7518257a : 0313fe48 7518257b 75182555 751b600c : Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkView::Run+0xe
0313fe40 7518244a : 75182555 751b600c 0313fe78 7518244b : twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run+0x26
0313fe50 757eff28 : 0313fe60 00681988 0067dd98 00681988 : twinapi_appcore!CWrlLightweightHandlerBase::ReleaseMarshalData+0x11a
0313fe80 772c7cf6 : 00000000 003ff398 00000000 00000000 : shcore!SHCreateThreadRef+0x200
0313ff10 00000000 : 00000000 772c7ce1 00000000 00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x16


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
CoreClr!CFindDependentWrappersCallback::OnFoundDependentWrapper+76
6e56525e 4604     mov         r4,r0

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  coreclr!CFindDependentWrappersCallback::OnFoundDependentWrapper+76

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: CoreClr

IMAGE_NAME:  CoreClr.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  530f2d64

STACK_COMMAND:  ~6s ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  c0000194_coreclr!CFindDependentWrappersCallback::OnFoundDependentWrapper+76

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  c0000194_coreclr!CFindDependentWrappersCallback::OnFoundDependentWrapper+76

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  c0000194

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  CoreClr.dll

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  CFindDependentWrappersCallback::OnFoundDependentWrapper

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  CoreClr.dll!CFindDependentWrappersCallback::OnFoundDependentWrapper

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang_c0000194_CoreClr.dll!CFindDependentWrappersCallback::OnFoundDependentWrapper

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:application_hang_busyhang_c0000194_coreclr.dll!cfinddependentwrapperscallback::onfounddependentwrapper

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {6bb64e73-a7aa-99d8-8d70-f0d75aab370a}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```